# How to connet with server pc and client pc

Tags: linux, server, centos, client, portforwarding

I have two PC. so i build up One is Server(CentOS)and the other is client(window)
i want to access my server by url like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:portnum on client pc
so i try to portforwarding but i can't access to server.

the method i used
1

## firewall-config > portforwarding > plus localport but not access

2
i used iptables but not access

i think the server is completely builded. like apache...
Tell me how to access with url on client pc

Comment: Do you need that your client can connect to Apache on web-server? Is your client and web-server in the same network?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install webserver (like: Apache or Nginx) and configure it to point to specific path to access it from URL